Can't connect to ClickHouse container
There is a running ClickHouse container
clickhouse-server:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    container_name: clickhouse-server
    ports:
        - '8123:8123'
        - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
        - ./db:/var/lib/clickhouse
    ulimits:
        nofile: 262144

There are configured connection parameters in .env
CLICKHOUSE_HOST=clickhouse-server
CLICKHOUSE_PORT=8123
CLICKHOUSE_DATABASE=memorial_analitucs
CLICKHOUSE_USERNAME=default
CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=
CLICKHOUSE_TIMEOUT_CONNECT=5
CLICKHOUSE_TIMEOUT_QUERY=5

When performing the migration, it returns the following error
2024_04_18_182025_create_analytics_table ............................................................................................ 3,710ms FAIL

  ClickHouseDB\Exception\QueryException 

  Could not resolve host: clickhouse-server

When clicking on the link http://localhost:8123 outputs "OK". Can you tell me what the problem might be?

Adding a network parameter worked.

config/database.php open add


'clickhouse' => [
            'driver' => 'clickhouse',
            'host' => env('CLICKHOUSE_HOST'),
            'port' => env('CLICKHOUSE_PORT','8123'),
            'database' => env('CLICKHOUSE_DATABASE','default'),
            'username' => env('CLICKHOUSE_USERNAME','default'),
            'password' => env('CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD',''),
            'timeout_connect' => env('CLICKHOUSE_TIMEOUT_CONNECT',2),
            'timeout_query' => env('CLICKHOUSE_TIMEOUT_QUERY',2),
            'https' => (bool)env('CLICKHOUSE_HTTPS', null),
            'retries' => env('CLICKHOUSE_RETRIES', 0),
            'settings' => [ // optional
                'max_partitions_per_insert_block' => 300,
            ],
        ], 



under "connections" array put it and try again.

Please use the clickhouse/clickhouse-server image. yandex/clickhouse-server:latest is using 22.1, and is out of support.

Adding a network parameter worked in container

Adding a network parameter worked in container.

Good luck, I forgot the issue
